How to properly handle backspace character in a command line input?
I want to backspace characters to be evaluated in the command line.
For instance, I want to simulate typing lss into the command line, and pressing backspace, which should evaluate to ls.
When I type $'lss\b \b' in the command line, I got the following error instead.
bash: $`lss\b \b`: command not found

It seems like bash is taking the command literally instead of applying the backspace.
When I type echo $'lss\b \b' instead, it correctly evaluates to ls
The reason I want this to work is because I am working on a web terminal that connects with an actual terminal in the backend through SSH, and I am passing each keystroke character by character to the actual terminal instead of maintaining a buffer.
So when a user presses backspace in the web terminal, the backspace would be sent directly to the backend terminal's standard input.
Apart from "\b \b", I have also tried with "\x7f", "\x08" and none of them work.

It doesn't evaluate to ls, run echo $'lss\b \b' | od -t x1 -t a and you'll see that the backspaces are still there.

@oguzismail right thanks for pointing that out, do you have any idea how to achieve the effect of "ls" in the command line even after applying the escape characters?

Try forcing ssh to create a pty by running it with the -tt option.

Or, perform your own buffering and line editing, and only send the result when the user commits it with a newline.

@oguzismail thanks a lot! Making SSH create a pty works and is exactly what I am looking for, appreciate your help!

Backspaces are handled by the terminal driver, or an interactive shell's call to the readline library. They're not processed in non-interactive input.

The two directions of terminal emulation (keypress vs. stuff to display) are completely unrelated. If you execute echo ls you are not simulating typing the letters l and s, you are sending these letters in the opposite direction. In order to synthesize keypresses, you need access to the pty's master side, or do an ioctl(TIOCSTI) (disabled by default in newer kernels) or fake X11 events to the graphical emulator, or alike. It's not as easy as sending letters to the terminal to display. Once you've figured it out, BS keypress is probably byte 0x7F (maybe 0x08) in this direction.
